# Given correlation of X and Y, and x, find y

Tags: correlation

I have two time series `X` and `Y` and their correlation.

If I am given `x` at a particular time, how do I find out what `y` at that time should be?

Is it finding the expected value of `y`, `E(Y|X=x)`? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Asuming unit variance of both variables :

Y = corr*X + sqroot(1-corr^2)X

Hence to use the formula you need to use standardized X and Y

Comment: What is this formula called? I'd like to understand it before using it. Thanks

Comment: This formula cant be correct... This looks more like linear regression. Its similar but they aren't the same.

Comment: You are right, Wei Zeng: because correlation contains no information about the means, there's no way to predict $y$ at all.  If you had information about the means you could indeed regress $y$ on $x$--but the formula quoted here would be wrong (even after standardizing $x$ and $y$).  Refer to standard formulas for regression coefficients posted elsewhere on this site or in regression textbooks.